# how to add a record to a table that has a reflexive relation?

Tags: sql, sql-server

it say's the insert statement conflicted with the foreign key same table constraint ,
how to insert the first record if his superior already doesn't exist

this is my code

```
create table Employe(
    Matricule int identity primary key,
    Nom nvarchar(50),
    Prenom nvarchar(50),
    DateNaiss date,
    Adresse nvarchar(50),
    Salaire float,
    Num_depart int foreign key references Departement(Num_depart),
    Superieur int foreign key references Employe(Matricule)
)
```

Comment: Try using `NULL` for `Superieur` then update it later w/ correct (newly generated) value.

Answer (score 1):

You would just add the employee without a superieur:

```
insert into Employe (Nom, Prenom, DateNaiss, Adresse, Salaire)
    values ('Head', 'Honcho', '1900-01-01', 'Heaven Court', 1e9);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ad1259021d282175cea1f2ae10e8d91b) is a db<>fiddle.  (The db<>fiddle comments out the department reference because you have not provided that in your question.)

Note that `salaire` should be `numeric`/`decimal`, not `float`.  You want an exact value, not an approximate value for this column.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a supervisor for an employee, you should insert it before inserting the employee's row. However, if there is no supervisor at all, then you can simply set the `Superieur` column to `NULL` when you insert your employee.